# Django FilteredSelectMultiple widget change tooltip title

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, widget

I`m using Django 1.9 with the following:

models.py:

```
class LocationPoint(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    radius = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
from api.models import *

class PopulationConstraintsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location_point = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=LocationPoint.objects.all(),
        widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("location point", is_stacked=False)
    )
```

And template.html

```
<div class="row">
    {{ form.location_point }}
</div>
```

The result is:
[image]

How can I change the Tooltip title that shows up when I hover with the mouse over the objects in Location Point model (In the sample the tooltip is showing "TelAviv")?

The html generated automatically by the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it by using the whole div output from F12 with a little change:

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="filtered" id="id_location_point_from" name="location_point_old">
    {% for c in  form.fields.location_point.queryset%}
        <option value="{{ c.id }}" title="My Title">{{  c.title }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```